# Why does this remove duplicate function in Haskell has two arguments instead of one?

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates

help me understand why the function `removeDuplicates` has only one argument, but the function `rdHelper` that is under it has two? It works, and there are no errors trying it out on a list.

```
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] 
removeDuplicates = rdHelper []     
    where rdHelper seen [] = seen  
          rdHelper seen (x:xs)
              | x `elem` seen = rdHelper seen xs 
              | otherwise = rdHelper (seen ++ [x]) xs
```

Perhaps its linked to state-variable? But I'm not sure what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an error in Willem's final answer, to remove all duplicates shouldn't be:

```
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] 
removeDuplicates = rdHelper []     
    where rdHelper seen [] = []  
          rdHelper seen (x:xs)
              | x `elem` seen = rdHelper seen xs 
              | otherwise = x : rdHelper (x:seen) XS
```

If in the 3rd line you return "seen" in the end you will get a duplicated list since you are also emitting all the unseen elements.

Comment: I remember that Williem's answer was wrong and I had to brain it out myself! Props for giving the right answer after all these years.

I've moved from university and am learning React for 8 months now! That language is beautiful!

Answer (score 5):

In order to remove duplicates, you need to somehow store what **values you have already seen**. That's why the variable is called `seen`. Initially in the recursion, you haven't seen any elements so `seen` is empty.

Each time you *emit* a value however, you add it to the accumulator `seen`. Say for instance you call `removeDuplicates [1,2,3,1,4,2]`. Then it will be evaluated like:

```
removeDuplicates [1,2,3,1,4,2]
    rdHelper [] [1,2,3,1,4,2]
        (1 : rdHelper [1] [2,3,1,4,2])
```

so now `rdHelper` will be called and we know `1` is already emitted so we should filter it out. Next we perform:

```
removeDuplicates [1,2,3,1,4,2]
    rdHelper [] [1,2,3,1,4,2]
        (1 : rdHelper [1] [2,3,1,4,2])
            (1 : 2 : rdHelper [1,2] [3,1,4,2])
                (1 : 2 : 3 : rdHelper [1,2,3] [1,4,2])
```

So now we encouter a situation where `1` is in the head of the second list but because it is also an `elem` of `seen`, we will ignore that element.

There is a bug in your code since `rdHelper` never emits something. Note furthermore that you can improve performance by adding to the head (adding to the head will not change the semantics of the program, but will make it run faster):

```
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] 
removeDuplicates = rdHelper []     
    where rdHelper _ [] = []  
          rdHelper seen (x:xs)
              | x `elem` seen = rdHelper seen xs 
              | otherwise = x : rdHelper (x:seen) xs
--                          ^emit element  ^add to head
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, your post explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

`rdHelper` is a helper function that accumulates a list of those elements that were seen, as well as the remaining list of elements from the original list. Because there is no mutation in Haskell, both accumulator lists are passed in as parameters to the helper function, and it calls itself recursively.

Comment: "Because there is no mutation in Haskell, both accumulator lists are passed in as parameters to the helper function. "

Please can you elaborate bit more on that?

Comment: You mentioned "state variable" in your original post, so it makes me think you have experience with imperative languages. The term "variable" in Haskell doesn't make much sense because all values are immutable. There is no "state" that can change, and functions can only return values based upon the values that were passed in as parameters.